# Move one site in Wordpress Multisite setup

Tags: wordpress, database-administration

I have a Multisite Wordpress setup with a dev box and a live. Whenever my developers change a theme on one of the sites or add a page/post/any other content on the deb box, I have to take the whole db and all wordpress files and move them to live.

I can take care of the changes in the files through svn but how can I copy only the changeset in the database to live. I don't want to copy the whole db every time especially since there might be new comments (for example) on live that I don't want overwritten.